# jpegenc - Encoding + Storing using VideoWrite() OpenCV function

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, gstreamer, encode

The following code is working fine to **capture the data**, **Decode** & **store the decoded data** in a file "out.h364" without performing an encoding operation.

```
cv::VideoCapture cap("filesrc location=720p.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux.video_0 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264, alignment=nal ! omxh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false async=false",cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);

VideoWriter video("appsrc ! videoconvert ! filesink location=out.h264", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER,0,60,Size(1280,720),true); 

cap >> frame;

video.write(frame);
```

Now I wanted to **perform encode operation** before storing it into a file. I tried the below code to encode->store it in a file using the **"jpegenc"** encoder.

```
VideoWriter video("appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, width=1280,height=720, framerate=60/1, format=BGR ! jpegenc ! filesink location=out.mp4", cv::CAP_GSTREAMER,0,60,Size(1280,720),true); 

cap >> frame;

video.write(frame);
```

**Problem:**: It is writing to the **out.mp4** file but I am not able to play it back. It seems it is not storing the data properly.

can anyone guide me to perform the encoding and then store it to the file?

Comment: In your second step, ```imshow("frame",frame)``` working properly? Also how can you be sure at the first step, it is storing data to out.h264 properly?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk yes it is working properly